# PHP IF / ELSEIF / ELSE NOT WORKING

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP script that takes variables passed from an HTML form and updates a flat file. The problem is that the simple if / elseif / else statement is not working, specifically, it does not open the correct file when performing the comparison. The input from the form will always write to the last file, i.e. gcads3.txt. I have tested that the correct details are being passed from the form to the script, i.e. one, two or three is passed to $col correctly, so I know it's the comparison that is faulty. I have checked the if / elseif / else syntax based on the PHP documentation and other posts on this issue so, what am I missing please?? Thank you in advance.

HTML code:

```
<form action="updategcads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Enter the column to add the new line to:</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="col" value="one"/> Column 1 
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type="radio" name="col" value="two"/> Column 2 
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type="radio" name="col" value="three"/> Column 3
  </p>
  <p>Enter the new line to add:<br><span>(enter the name)</span></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="advs" size="50"/></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Update"/></p>
</form>
```

updategcads.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
  $col = $_POST["col"]; 
  $line = $_POST["advs"]; 
}

if ($col=="one")
{
  $file = fopen("../gcads1.txt", "a") or die("unable to open $file: $!");
} 
elseif ($col=="two") 
{
  $file = fopen("../gcads2.txt", "a") or die("unable to open $file: $!");
} 
else
{
  $file = fopen("../gcads3.txt", "a") or die("unable to open $file: $!");
}

fwrite($file, $line);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Use strcmp to compare strings in php

Comment: You should try logging one of your comparison results. You'll see that it doesn't quite make sense. Once you've done that I'd recommend checking the difference between === and ==. An finally checking what the strcomp() function has to offer.

Comment: Side note, you don't need to use post for this, nor do you need this form to be multitype/form-data. You should enclose the whole comparison part within the isset check and try checking against a known value. isset($_POST['col']) - because $_POST is always set.

Comment: @Ali - definitely gonna look into this, thanks.

Comment: @kashalo - very helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Juuso Elo-Rauta - I checked the documentation for the difference between ==== and ==. I think the best answer is to use strcmp() too. Thanks.

Comment: @Kai-Qing - thank you, isset($_POST['col']) is way more efficient than what I am doing. To your other comment, you'd use GET instead of POST? Also, since you are a PHP expert, can you please explain why "else if" worked and  "elseif" didn't? Appreciate it!

Comment: @LuPitkat take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php it's not clear why it was not working for you as `elseif` but is for `else if`. What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this to work by changing "elseif" to "else if". I'm not sure why that worked, and the PHP documentation is unclear, so if anyone can shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: I think twisty summarized that above. It could be php versions, but honestly it's never done that for me so I am not positive why it would for you. There's opinions about the usage of GET/POST but anymore the concept of read/write protocol in form handling is like legacy habits more than proper coding. If your receiving script is done well, it doesn't matter much in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider the following code. Not much different, yet may allow for growth.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['col']) {
  $col = $_POST["col"]; 
  $line = $_POST["advs"]; 
}
$nums = array(
  "one" => 1,
  "two" => 2,
  "three" => 3,
  "four" => 4,
  "five" => 5.
  "six" => 6,
  "seven" => 7,
  "eight" => 8,
  "nine" => 9,
  "zero" => 0
);

$file = fopen("../gcads" . $nums[$col] . ".txt", "a") or die("unable to open $file: $!");

fwrite($file, $line);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Alternately, you can use `switch()` too. Food for thought.